# Php Session unset() with firefox

Tags: php, firefox

I'm trying to display error messages for when a user doesn't enter data in certain fields. If the user doesn't enter anything in a field I store that error in a Session. When the user hits enter and the session with error messages is set it should prevent the user from continuing and display the errors. When I display the errors I store the errors in the session in a variable then unset the session then loop through the errors, printing each one out. This works find on every browser except firefox.

In firefox, if I try to use unset() on the session anywhere on the page it wipes out the values in the variable as well. As if the variable references to the session. This is only a problem in firefox. I need to unset the session otherwise it affects any other pages that I have error messages printing out.

Anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Have discovered that the errors display on my localhost server for firefox, but not when I upload it to the web.

Comment: When you say unset the session do you mean you are `calling session_unset()` or are you `calling unset($_SESSION)` or do you mean you are just un-setting a single array key e.g. `unset($_SESSION['key'])`? It would be nice of you could copy into your post what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the error messages in an array and check to see if the array is empty?

```
$errors = array();

if(empty($_POST['variable']))
{
    $errors[] = "Variable empty.";
}

if(empty($errors))
{
    // Process form
}
else
{
    // Loop through the array and echo out each error messsage
}
```

This would make more sense and can be guaranteed to work within all browsers.

Comment: The way the system is set up is checking on error messages is on a second page and if the errors exist it redirects back to the previous page to display the errors. I can't change the way it is laid out, which is why I think they used sessions over just using arrays. It is just odd that it is only a issue for firefox.

Comment: Can you edit your main post to show the related code then please?

Answer (score 0):

This solution fixed my problem when I had a similar problem.

http://sofiac.us/resources/press/20120521_firefox_unset.php